# libraryDependencies Spark in build.sbt error (IntelliJ)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-scala

I am trying to learning Scala with Spark. I am following a tutorial but I am having an error, **when I try to import the library dependencies of Spark**:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.3"
```

**I am getting the following error**:

[image: Error librarydpendencies]

And I have 3 Unkwons artifacts.

[image: Unkwons artifacts]

What could be the problem here?

My code is so simple, it is just a Hello World.

Comment: What is your `scalaVersion`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to add to your `build.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "spark-core" at "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core"
```

Please note that this library is supported only for Scala 2.11 and Scala 2.12.

Comment: Thank you so much! Was that, I was using Scala version 2.13, no need resolvers.