# Unknown artifact. Not resolved or indexed”

Tags: scala, apache-spark, twitter

this is my sbt file :

```
name := "spark-twitter-stream-example"

version := "1.0.0"

scalaVersion := "2.13.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming" % "2.0.1",
  "org.apache.bahir" % "spark-streaming-twitter" % "2.0.1"
)
```

i  have this error

```
Unknown artifact. Not resolved or indexed”
```

please how i can update my dependency in built.sbt
please i need solution

Comment: **Spark** is not published for **Scala** `2.13` use a `2.12` version.

Comment: You can see at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming the versions of `spark-streaming` with their Scala versions compatibility.

Comment: Please see [libraryDependencies Spark in build.sbt error (IntelliJ)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65260968/2359227)

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me ( new version)

```
name := "spark-twitter-stream-example"

version := "1.0.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"



libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "3.0.1" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.bahir" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "2.4.0"
```

Comment: Are you sure `spark-streaming-twitter` supports **Spark** `3.x`? For what I can see in [**Mavencentral**](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.bahir/spark-streaming-twitter_2.12/2.4.0) it doesn't. - You may want to use **Spark** `2.4`.